# "wwwroot" folder for project in visual studio

Tags: angular, visual-studio, wwwroot

Why do we need "wwwroot" folder for project in visual studio? Using angular 14 and .net5

Tried to find about it but everywhere it says " the wwwroot folder in the ASP.NET Core project is treated as a web root folder."